# How put subtags autonumbering?

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, enumerate, itemize, tags

I created more tag for enumerate separately equations, propositions, lemmas etc. However, I would like that if an equation is put into a proposition then it is tagged as an equation of that proposition with a subtag: so, I wrote this code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,textwidth=17cm,textheight=25 cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposizione}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollario}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} 
\end{equation}
\begin{proposition}
\end{proposition}
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{proposition}
\end{proposition}
\begin{equation}
%If that the tag of last proposition is $n$ then I want that this equation is tagged with $n.1$ or $n.a$ or $n.i$
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
%If that the tag of last proposition is $n$ then I want that this equation is tagged with $n.2$ or $n.b$ or $n.ii$
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

but unfortunately it does not work. So how do I have to procede? Moreover, If I want numerate equations, propositions, lemmas etc. all together then do I have to procede with subtags in a different way? Could someone help me, please?

Comment: How should the very first equation be numbered? Right now the example you show suggests you want the numbers (1), (1.1), (1.2), (2.1a), (2.1b). You seem to be on the best path to utterly confound your readers `:-)`

Comment: @campa If you are referring to the first equation of al document naturally I want it is tagged with 1 whereas if you are referring to the first equation of subequation  structure then I wan that it is tagged e.g. with 2.1 or 2.a or 2.i if the principal strucutre (a theorem, a proposition) is tagged with 2. I hope I have explained myself. :-)